# MacBook Pro, OS X El Capitan - Photo Problems

Tags: finder, photos, graphics, library

I'm new to MacBooks and I take a lot of pictures. One of the things I appreciated of my previous Windows computer was that the photo organization was great.

On my Mac, when I download my photos into *Pictures* folder in Finder, it doesn't sync to my *Photos Library*. I have to go through and import every photo. And if I want to edit a photo in photos library, it doesn't update that same photo in my *Pictures* folder.

I have a blog so I'm all the time uploading photos online. And if I want to upload a photo that I edited and try to open it from Photo Library, it won't let me. It only pulls up the *Pictures* folder, which doesn't have any of my edits.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, when you sync photos with the app, pictures are copied in the Library, so it is actually created a new version of each photo. When you modify it in the app, you will only edit that copy, and not the original one.

If you want to access the edited photos, you have 2 options:

1. Just drag the pic from Photos to a specific folder: the photo will be copied again, with all the previous edits you made.
2. You can directly access the Library. Just go to Finder > Pictures > Photo Library. Right click on it > Show Package Contents > Masters: here you have all the photos, classified by date. Now you can treat each photo as it were in a normal folder.